# Is there a way to check whether a new row in a table agrees with entries in other tables? [SQL]

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I am using MySQL Workbench CE for a college assignment. I have 4 tables: `Applicants, Universities, Job, Interview`. `Interview` has foreign keys in the other 3 tables: `appID` (applicant ID), `uniID` (university ID) and `jobID` (job ID). Additionally, the `job` table has a `uni` column, which is a foreign key to `universities.id`. Essentially, each job has a job number and a university associated with it. Each interview has an applicant, a job and a university, in addition to some other information.

I am trying to figure out how to check whether the job offering (job number + its associated university) entered into the `interview` table actually exists in the `job` table.

For example, if the only row in `job` is:

`ID  |  JobID  |  UniID | ..
 1       1         1      .`

Then the `interview` table **shouldn't** accept something like:

`ID  | AppID | JobID | UniID | ...
 x      x      1       2      .`

as there is no job with `JobID = 1` and `UniID = 2`.

`SELECT * FROM job as J LEFT JOIN interview as I ON J.uni = I.uniid WHERE J.id = I.jobid` is a check I came up with for this issue, however, I'm not sure whether I should attempt to use it in a trigger or as part of an assertion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for a *foreign key* relationship.

If the `jobs` table does not already have a primary/unique key on the two columns, then define one:

```
alter table jobs add constraint unq_jobs_jobid_uniid on job(jobID, uniID);
```

Then, you can add a foreign key to `interviews`:

```
alter table interviews add constraint fk_interviews_jobid_uniID
    foreign key (jobID, uniID) references job(jobID, uniID);
```

Note that this works even if `jobID` is already the primary key in `jobs`.